# Design an algorithm to predict words based on a skeleton from a given dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, strings, mathematics, machine-learning

The model I'm building first selects a secret word at random from a list. The model which uses an API then returns a row of underscores (space separated)—one for each letter in the secret word—and asks the user to guess a letter. If the user guesses a letter that is in the word, the word is redisplayed with all instances of that letter shown in the correct positions, along with any letters correctly guessed on previous turns. If the letter does not appear in the word, the user is charged with an incorrect guess. The user keeps guessing letters until either (1) the user has correctly guessed all the letters in the word or (2) the user has made six incorrect guesses.

I'm working on an algorithm which is permitted to use a training set of approximately 250,000 dictionary words.

I have built and providing here with a basic, working algorithm. This algorithm will match the provided masked string (e.g. a _ _ l e) to all possible words in the dictionary, tabulate the frequency of letters appearing in these possible words, and then guess the letter with the highest frequency of appearence that has not already been guessed. If there are no remaining words that match then it will default back to the character frequency distribution of the entire dictionary.

This benchmark strategy is successful approximately 18% of the time. I aim to design an algorithm that significantly outperforms this benchmark.

```
import random
import string
import time
import re
import collections
import math
import json
import requests
import numpy as np
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlencode, urlparse
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

####This is a part of the larger code and this code is written by the according to the API mode here
try:
    from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlencode, urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import parse_qs, urlparse
    from urllib import urlencode

from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

######Start of the code up for review

class HangmanAPI(object):
    def __init__(self, access_token=None, session=None, timeout=None):
        self.hangman_url = self.determine_hangman_url()
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.session = session or requests.Session()
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.guessed_letters = []
        
        full_dictionary_location = "words_250000_train.txt"
        self.full_dictionary = self.build_dictionary(full_dictionary_location)        
        self.full_dictionary_common_letter_sorted = collections.Counter("".join(self.full_dictionary)).most_common()
        
        self.current_dictionary = []

        # Initialize the decision tree model and vectorizer here
        self.decision_tree_model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
        self.vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', lowercase=False, binary=True)
        self.target_labels = [chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(26)]

        # Fit the decision tree model with the full dictionary once during initialization
        X = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(self.full_dictionary)
        y = np.array([word[-1] for word in self.full_dictionary])
        self.decision_tree_model.fit(X, y)
        
    @staticmethod
    def determine_hangman_url():
        links = ['https://trexsim.com', 'https://sg.trexsim.com']

        data = {link: 0 for link in links}

        for link in links:
            requests.get(link)

            for i in range(10):
                s = time.time()
                requests.get(link)
                data[link] = time.time() - s

        link = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0][0]
        link += '/trexsim/hangman'
        return link

    def guess(self, word):
        # Clean the word so that we strip away the space characters
        # Replace "_" with "." as "." indicates any character in regular expressions
        clean_word = word[::2].replace("_", ".")

        # Find length of the passed word
        len_word = len(clean_word)

        # Grab current dictionary of possible words from self object, initialize a new possible words dictionary to empty
        current_dictionary = self.current_dictionary
        new_dictionary = []

        # Iterate through all of the words in the old plausible dictionary
        for dict_word in current_dictionary:
            # Continue if the word is not of the appropriate length
            if len(dict_word) != len_word:
                continue

            # If dictionary word is a possible match, then add it to the current dictionary
            if re.match(clean_word, dict_word):
                new_dictionary.append(dict_word)

        # Overwrite old possible words dictionary with the updated version
        self.current_dictionary = new_dictionary

        # If there are no remaining words that match, default back to the ordering of the full dictionary
        if not new_dictionary:
            sorted_letter_count = self.full_dictionary_common_letter_sorted
        else:
            # Update the current dictionary with the new_dictionary
            self.current_dictionary = new_dictionary

            # Get the count of each letter at each position in the current dictionary
            letter_counts = [{letter: sum(1 for word in self.current_dictionary if word[i] == letter) for letter in self.target_labels}
                             for i in range(len(clean_word))]

            # Choose the character with the highest count at the next position
            next_position = len(self.guessed_letters)
            guessed_letter = max(letter_counts[next_position], key=letter_counts[next_position].get)

            # Remove the guessed letter from the possible letters in current_dictionary
            self.current_dictionary = [word for word in self.current_dictionary if guessed_letter not in word]

            return guessed_letter


        # Return the letter with the highest information gain that hasn't been guessed yet
        for letter, info_gain in sorted_letter_count:
            if letter not in self.guessed_letters:
                return letter

        # If all letters have been guessed, revert to ordering of full dictionary (fallback)
        return self.full_dictionary_common_letter_sorted[0][0]

    def make_decision(self, word_pattern):
        # Use decision tree model to make a prediction
        X = self.vectorizer.transform(self.current_dictionary)
        
        # Get the target labels (last character of each word) for the decision tree model
        y = np.array([word[-1] for word in self.current_dictionary])
        
        self.decision_tree_model.fit(X, y)

        # Transform the word pattern using the vectorizer
        pattern_vectorized = self.vectorizer.transform([word_pattern])

        # Make a prediction for the next letter probabilities
        next_letter_probabilities = self.decision_tree_model.predict_proba(pattern_vectorized)[0]

        # Get the index of the predicted letter (letter with the highest probability)
        next_letter_index = np.argmax(next_letter_probabilities)

        # Convert the predicted index back to the letter
        guessed_letter = self.target_labels[next_letter_index]

        return guessed_letter

    def compute_conditional_probabilities(self, word_pattern):
        # Count the occurrence of each letter in the possible words
        full_dict_string = "".join(self.current_dictionary)
        c = collections.Counter(full_dict_string)

        # Calculate the total count of letters in the possible words
        total_letter_count = sum(c.values())

        # Calculate the conditional probabilities of each letter given the word pattern
        letter_probabilities = {}
        for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
            if letter not in self.guessed_letters:
                pattern_with_letter = word_pattern.replace(".", letter)
                matching_words_count = sum(1 for word in self.current_dictionary if re.match(pattern_with_letter, word))
                conditional_probability = matching_words_count / total_letter_count
                # Calculate the information gain using entropy (log2)
                information_gain = -conditional_probability * math.log2(conditional_probability) if conditional_probability > 0 else 0
                letter_probabilities[letter] = information_gain

        return letter_probabilities

    def build_dictionary(self, dictionary_file_location):
        text_file = open(dictionary_file_location, "r")
        full_dictionary = text_file.read().splitlines()
        text_file.close()
        return full_dictionary

####This is a part of the larger code and this code is written by the according to the API mode here
                
    def start_game(self, practice=True, verbose=True):
        # reset guessed letters to empty set and current plausible dictionary to the full dictionary
        self.guessed_letters = []
        self.current_dictionary = self.full_dictionary
                         
        response = self.request("/new_game", {"practice":practice})
        if response.get('status')=="approved":
            game_id = response.get('game_id')
            word = response.get('word')
            tries_remains = response.get('tries_remains')
            if verbose:
                print("Successfully start a new game! Game ID: {0}. # of tries remaining: {1}. Word: {2}.".format(game_id, tries_remains, word))
            while tries_remains>0:
                # get guessed letter from user code
                guess_letter = self.guess(word)
                    
                # append guessed letter to guessed letters field in hangman object
                self.guessed_letters.append(guess_letter)
                if verbose:
                    print("Guessing letter: {0}".format(guess_letter))
                    
                try:    
                    res = self.request("/guess_letter", {"request":"guess_letter", "game_id":game_id, "letter":guess_letter})
                except HangmanAPIError:
                    print('HangmanAPIError exception caught on request.')
                    continue
                except Exception as e:
                    print('Other exception caught on request.')
                    raise e
               
                if verbose:
                    print("Sever response: {0}".format(res))
                status = res.get('status')
                tries_remains = res.get('tries_remains')
                if status=="success":
                    if verbose:
                        print("Successfully finished game: {0}".format(game_id))
                    return True
                elif status=="failed":
                    reason = res.get('reason', '# of tries exceeded!')
                    if verbose:
                        print("Failed game: {0}. Because of: {1}".format(game_id, reason))
                    return False
                elif status=="ongoing":
                    word = res.get('word')
        else:
            if verbose:
                print("Failed to start a new game")
        return status=="success"
        
    def my_status(self):
        return self.request("/my_status", {})
    
    def request(self, path, args=None, post_args=None, method=None):
        if args is None:
            args = dict()
        if post_args is not None:
            method = "POST"

        # Add `access_token` to post_args or args if it has not already been included.
        if self.access_token:
            # If post_args exists, we assume that args either does not exist or it does not need `access_token`.
            if post_args and "access_token" not in post_args:
                post_args["access_token"] = self.access_token
            elif "access_token" not in args:
                args["access_token"] = self.access_token

        time.sleep(0.2)

        num_retry, time_sleep = 50, 2
        for it in range(num_retry):
            try:
                response = self.session.request(
                    method or "GET",
                    self.hangman_url + path,
                    timeout=self.timeout,
                    params=args,
                    data=post_args,
                    verify=False
                )
                break
            except requests.HTTPError as e:
                response = json.loads(e.read())
                raise HangmanAPIError(response)
            except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:
                if it + 1 == num_retry:
                    raise
                time.sleep(time_sleep)

        headers = response.headers
        if 'json' in headers['content-type']:
            result = response.json()
        elif "access_token" in parse_qs(response.text):
            query_str = parse_qs(response.text)
            if "access_token" in query_str:
                result = {"access_token": query_str["access_token"][0]}
                if "expires" in query_str:
                    result["expires"] = query_str["expires"][0]
            else:
                raise HangmanAPIError(response.json())
        else:
            raise HangmanAPIError('Maintype was not text, or querystring')

        if result and isinstance(result, dict) and result.get("error"):
            raise HangmanAPIError(result)
        return result
    
class HangmanAPIError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, result):
        self.result = result
        self.code = None
        try:
            self.type = result["error_code"]
        except (KeyError, TypeError):
            self.type = ""

        try:
            self.message = result["error_description"]
        except (KeyError, TypeError):
            try:
                self.message = result["error"]["message"]
                self.code = result["error"].get("code")
                if not self.type:
                    self.type = result["error"].get("type", "")
            except (KeyError, TypeError):
                try:
                    self.message = result["error_msg"]
                except (KeyError, TypeError):
                    self.message = result

        Exception.__init__(self, self.message)
```

I am trying to implement a unique method which is under the "guess" method.

The dataset to try the training can be found: [here](https://iitk-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/devbhavin20_iitk_ac_in/EbDnTyKFdehBjlVYZMLgkckB4yKhszwMkV8ZWwF1-wzwdQ?e=4fIgSk)

Comment: Is the current code suitable for review yet? Please [take the Tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and then describe your authorship of each OP class & method.

Comment: Yes the code works, and I believe each class and method has been described here

Comment: Who wrote `start_game()`, and the exception class?

Comment: that is a part of a larger API function @J_H for the algorithm i believe this should be more than enough

Comment: I was asking for the name of the person who wrote the "You'll likely not need to modify any of the code below" line in the original submission.

Comment: Guess: some down-votes are from the impression that not all of the code presented for review is your own - and you don't tell this from 3rd party code. Suggestion: Present what is not your own coding in a separate code block, nested in a block quote. Explicitly state whether or not you'd appreciate views on that part, too.

Comment: @greybeard many thanks, i did not know about these rules. i have made those changes here

Comment: @J_H many thanks for the clarification. i wasn't aware of the rules and regulations. i am new to this space. i made those changes in the code.

Comment: (On [CS@SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/161242/19966)) (I don't consider this an unwelcome cross-post: while the answers may overlap in *algorithm*, the focus is far enough apart.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, the source code looks structured - some lines are overly long, comments as well as code.

- There is more to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation) than `Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.` and `Use 4 spaces per indentation level. [optional for continuation lines]`; in particular,
  use [*Documentation Strings*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257). (I wish it strongly recommended including [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#module-doctest)s.)
- There are useful comments like

  ```
        # Clean the word by stripping away the space characters
        clean_word = word[::2]
  ```

  , useless ones

  ```
        # Find length of the passed word
        len_word = len(word)
  ```

  , and there are comments from irritating to misleading

  ```
        # Find length of the passed word
        len_word = len(clean_word)
  ```

  - `clean_word` is neither the parameter passed, nor is its value the value passed (unless `len(word) < 2`).
  (This particular one might have happened to me - I might have written "pseudo code comments" first, to later code the parts: one needs to take care detail comments&code are consistent.)
  And there are restricting comments:
  Following `# Iterate through all of the words in the old plausible dictionary`,
  who'd expect anything but `for ‹word› in current_dictionary:`?
  `# Need a dictionary of words still possible` allows `filter()` as well as comprehensions.
- `HangmanAPI` as a name suggests a single responsibility, which would be a good thing.
  I see *business logic* here, too.
- `.full_dictionary` currently is an instance variable - fine if the contents can be selected at instantiation (e.g. make `full_dictionary_location` an `__init__()` parameter with a default). Otherwise I'd prefer a class data member.
- In `guess()`, you check the length of every word in every dictionary considered.
  Length doesn't change: have `build_dictionar…()` return dictionaries by length.
- You use lists for dictionaries: measure the impact of using sets instead. Or strings (words separated by a non-character), to be used with [`finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer).
- `26` is a *magic number*:
  `self.target_labels = [chr(o) for o in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)]`
- In `guess()`, the `else:` statement starts with a redundant assignment - and ends with a `return`: use `if new_dictionary:` instead.
- if not going *dictionary is a string&finditer*, it may pay to compile REs while there are lots of strings to check

Comment: (Didn't discern rhythm or rhyme with the approach presented.)